# Confused at transferring an ambiguous grammar to an unambiguous one

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, ambiguous-grammar

An ambiguous grammar is given and I am asked to rewrite the grammar to make it unambiguous. In fact, I don't know why the given grammar is ambiguous, let alone rewriting it to an unambiguous one.

The given grammar is S -> SS | a | b , and I have four choices:

```
A: S -> Sa | Sb | epsilon  

B: S -> SS’
   S’-> a | b  

C: S -> S | S’
   S’-> a | b 

D: S -> Sa | Sb.
```

For each choice, I have already know that D is incorrect because it generates no strings at all,C is incorrect because it only matches the strings 'a' and 'b'.

However, I think the answer is A while the correct answer is B.I think B is wrong because it just generates S over and over again, and B can't deal with empty strings.

1. Why is the given grammar ambiguous？
2. Why is A incorrect while B is correct？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original grammar is ambiguous because multiple right-most (or left-most) derivations are possible for any string of at least three letters. For example:

```
S -> SS -> SSS -> SSa -> Saa -> aaa
S -> SS -> Sa  -> SSa -> Saa -> aaa
```

The first one corresponds, roughly speaking, to the parse `a(aa)` while the second to the parse `(aa)a`.

None of the alternatives is correct. `A` incorrectly matches ε while `B` does not match anything (like `D`). If `B` were, for example,

```
S  -> SS' | S'
S' -> a | b
```

it would be correct. (This grammar is left-associative.)